# Alamofire (iOS) keep response in cache?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, request, alamofire

I make a GET request in order to get some infos on a server `Alamofire.request(.GET, url)`, then I make an update of these infos in my app  `Alamofire.request(.PUT, url, parameters: params)` which that really change infos on the server but when I remake the same GET request, the infos are not refreshed on the client side.

I tried to change the cache policy but nothing append.

Have you any idea from where that can come ?

Comment: How have you tried to change cache policy?

Comment: @Avt Yes I've tried, but it does not change.